# URL's being written absolutely in some places and relatively in others

Tags: administrator, sef

Link alias double up.
My template for the Admin panel is showing a blank white page because the URL's used to resolve the CSS, images, javascript etc are incorrect, despite the page itself having some components that are correctly processed by the Joomla! PHP

**EXAMPLE**

`<link href="my-page.com/administrator/templates/isis/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-page.com/media/jui/css/chosen.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="`**templates/isis/css/template.css**`" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css">
html { display:none }
  </style>
  <script src="`**my-page.com/media/system/js/mootools-core.js**`" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="my-page.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

As you can see some of the links are correct, some are not. All this code is generated by `<jdoc:include type="head" />` in the index.php file under `administrator/templates/isis/login.php`
templates/isis/css/template.css is correct whilst mypage.com/media/system/js/mootools-core.js is not correct as it's a relative link so it resolves to my-page.com/administrator/my-page.com/media/system/js/mootools-core.js...

I don't think it's SEF.

It's also happening on my root index page too, not just the admin page.
Been stuck on this for way too long.

Comment: You do not describe how you are creating the wrong Urls. Eg. JRoute(....)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I'm not creating the URL's, Joomla! is. It's a default install on which I simply converted a bootstrap theme to work with it, but I didn't make any changes whatsoever to the back-end, core or Administrator template (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: I've added an example of what's happening, please note the incorrect url's generated which are correct if used absolutely, but these are trying to be resolved relatively which effectively doubles up the alias of the site - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think I've found my issue after having installed a new version of Joomla and getting the same result. I've misconfigured Apache. I'm using virtual hosts and my httpd.conf has entries to redirect some url's but I believe it's doing this for all url's causing this misdirection issue. Not related to Joomla.</strike>

I do apologise for consuming anyone's time on the matter, I will update this answer when I've fixed it.

*Edit: this is not the cause, it appears to be* **SEF** *related..*

*Edit 2: SEF did not help things but the **problem was the live_site constant in configuration.php** if set to my sites address, presumably because I'm using a virtual host setup, Apache AND Joomla! couldn't effectively sort out the URL's, it was writing them 3 times in a row in some cases.*

## **Solution**

Set `live_site = '';` (empty), in `configuration.php` Now all the URL's are fine and all content is showing, Admin page is accessible again.**

Comment: Nope actually this is a Joomla issue, not just Apache.

With SEF on I get `sitename.com/sitename.com/sitename.com/media/image1.jpg` etc type links, which obviously breaks CSS, content, images etc.
With SEF off, the index page loads fine but the links on the page still go to `sitename.com/sitename.com/media/image1.jpg` etc

What on earth is going on..